# How to mask byte value in Java?

Tags: java, byte, masking, bitwise-and

My problem is some like this.

I have some calculation in byte in Java. In some calculation I get my desired result "2a" in byte value but in some calculation I get "ffffff9a" in byte value. I just want the "9a" value in from the result "ffffff9a". I tried this but didn't work.

```
byte a = (byte) b & 0xff;
```

where b have value "ffffff9a" byte value.

But while displaying the same process works like

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff));
```

Where am I going wrong? What can I do to get my desired value?

Thanks

---

Actually I am trying to convert 8 bit character into gsm 7 bit. Also if someone there can help me through this, it would be helpful too. String is stored as a byte array and I have to convert this string or 8 bit bytes into 7 bit.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, double check you are testing it correctly? Maybe show the whole routine? Also is 'b' a byte type?

Comment: Seems fine to me `System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(0xffffff9a & 0xff));` prints `9a` http://ideone.com/ikxuO

Comment: yes b is type byte, and printing is fine, I want to store value in variable, where the problem is

Answer (score 8):

The `byte` type in Java is *signed*. It has a range of [-128, 127].

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(a & 0xff)); // note a, not b
```

Would show "the correct value" even though `a`, which is of type `byte`, will *contain a negative value* (`(byte)0x92`). That is, `(int)a == 0x92` will be false because the cast to `int` *keeps* the value, negative and all, while `(a & 0xff) == 0x92` will be true. This is because the bit-wise `&` promotes the expression to an `int` type while "masking away" the "sign bit" (not really sign bit, but artefact of two's complement).

See: [Java How To "Covert" Bytes](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/basics/how-to-convert-bytes.jspx)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial code was: `byte a = (byte) b & 0xff;`

The `(byte)` typecast only applied to the `b`, which is already a `byte`.  The `&` operator then widened that to an `int` so you got the result "ffffff9a" from the `int`.

You need to ensure that you typecast applies to the result of the `&`, not just to its first operand:

`byte a = (byte)(b & 0xff);`

Note the extra pair of parentheses.

Comment: I have tried that too(the extra parenthesis), but result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
//bit is zero base
public static boolean isSet(byte value, int bit)
{
    int b = (int)value & 0xff;
    b >>= bit;
    b &= 0x01;
    if( b != 0 )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public static byte setBit(byte value, int bit)
{
    int b = (int)value;

    b |= (1 << bit);
    return (byte)(b & 0xff);
}
public static byte clearBit(byte value, int bit)
{
    int b = (int)value;

    b &= ~(1 << bit);
    return (byte)(b & 0xff);
}
```